# passing a value from a function to a label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyserial

I want to pass or store a value from a function to a variable, then use that variable to put in a label.

I tried giving the global assignment to the variable but it gives an Error:  name 'num' is not defined. Did you mean: 'sum'?.

```
global num


def takeWeight():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 57600, timeout=1)

    while True:
        line = ser.readline()  # read a byte
        if line:
            num = line.decode().strip()  
            print(num)
    ser.close()


weightDisplay = ttk.Label(startScan_frame, text=num)
weightDisplay.grid(column=2, row=4)
weightDisplay.grid_configure(pady=20)
```

Comment: num = 0


def takeWeight():
    global num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're on the right track! But you're going about globals the wrong way a bit.
Any variable you define *outside a function* exists in the global scope. You use the `global` keyword *inside* your function to allow that function to modify the value of that global variable

```
def takeWeight():
    global num  # allow this function to modify the value of 'num'
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 57600, timeout=1)

    while True:
        line = ser.readline()  # read a byte
        if line:
            num = line.decode().strip()  
            print(num)
    ser.close()


num = ''  # declare 'num' as a placeholder in the global scope
weightDisplay = ttk.Label(startScan_frame, text=num)
weightDisplay.grid(column=2, row=4)
weightDisplay.grid_configure(pady=20)
```

That said, since this is tkinter, what you really want is to bind your `Label`'s `textvariable` attribute to a `tk.StringVar()`

So what does that mean?

```
def takeWeight():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 57600, timeout=1)

    while True:
        line = ser.readline()  # read a byte
        if line:
            num.set(line.decode().strip())  # call 'set' to update the value of 'num'
            print(num.get())  # call 'get' to retrieve the current value of 'num'
    ser.close()


num = tk.StringVar()  # create an instance of 'StringVar' to store your value
# and then bind that variable to your label - this way, whenever you update 'num'
# using 'num.set('whatever'), your label will update automatically!
weightDisplay = ttk.Label(startScan_frame, textvariable=num)
weightDisplay.grid(column=2, row=4)
weightDisplay.grid_configure(pady=20)
```

So far so good! Unfortunately, you're still going go run into a problem here because of the `While` loop! Blocking operations and loops don't play nicely with tkinter and will cause your GUI to hang. Fortunately, this is fixable too!

tkinter has a method called `after` that lets you essentially insert function calls into the GUI event loop. This way, you can poll your serial port for new info while still keeping your GUI running. You just need to modify `takeWeight` to use `after`

```
# 'ser' doesn't need to be declared *every* time 'takeWeight' is called,
# so let's move it into the global scope (this also lets us refer to 'ser'
# in the 'close' method described below!)
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 57600, timeout=1)
# let's also declare a placeholder that will store the id of the 'after' call
serial_loop_id = None


def takeWeight():
    global serial_loop_id
    line = ser.readline()  # read a byte
    if line:
        num.set(line.decode().strip())
    # use 'after' to call this function again after 100mS
    serial_loop_id = root.after(100, takeWeight)
```

Notice now that `ser.close()` isn't being called by `takeWeight` any more - you'll have to handle this slightly differently! In this case, you can just define a `close` function to stop the `takeWeight` loop and then call `ser.close`. Just call `close()` when you're ready.

```
def close():
    root.after_cancel(serial_loop_id)  # stop the 'takeWeight' polling loop
    ser.close()  # close the serial port
```

Note: `root.after()` and `root.after_cancel()` are assuming that your main instance of `tk.Tk` is called `root`. If you did something like `mainwindow = tk.Tk()`, use `mainwindow.after()` instead!

And as a final note, the serial polling in `takeWeight` won't start until you actually call the `takeWeight` function somewhere, a la `takeWeight()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the global variable by putting it inside the function as the global declaration is not doing anything outside of it. Below is an example of what I mean.

```
num = None

def takeWeight():
    global num
    ...
```

by making this change, you can update the global variable from inside the function without changing what the function does. The issue is that you would only be updating the global variable and not updating the text inside the label. To fix this you can reference the label itself by changing its tex then updating the window. below is the code that can be used.

```
def takeWeight():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 57600, timeout=1)

    while True:
        line = ser.readline()  # read a byte
        if line:
            weightDisplay.configure(text = line.decode().strip())  
            # then add your_window_name.update() and your_window_name.update_idletasks()
    ser.close()

weightDisplay = ttk.Label(startScan_frame, text="default text for label")
weightDisplay.grid(column=2, row=4, pady=20)
```

You also do not need a global variable. Just make sure you have a way to stop the infinite while loop created in the function. As it is currently shown, `ser.close()` will never get called. One way you can do this is by adding some condition within the while loop that once met will stop the loop. An example of this is shown below.

```
def takeWeight():
    should_run = True
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 57600, timeout=1)

    while should_run:
        
        ... #your code goes here
        
        if condition_is_met:
            should_run = False
    ser.close()
```

you could also just add a `break` statement if the condition is met and not need to change anything else to break out of the infinite loop.

Comment: This should work, but there are better and easier ways to update a `Label` than removing and re-adding it every time.

Comment: im pretty sure it can be done without removing and re-adding them by just updating the window but I'm not 100% sure it will work, it is safer to re-add the label because you are guaranteeing that the label is updated if it is shown.

Comment: It absolutely can be done without removing and re-adding the label. If you *need* to guarantee that updates are handled, it's best to call `root.update_idletasks()` after modifying your `Label` with `config`/`configure`, or by updating the variable bound to its `textvariable`

Comment: You are right, this is not actually needed and I was suggesting that the window gets updated afterward anyway. I updated my answer to convey this.